# Spark: need to persist() the DataFrame after every transformation & action?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark, need we to persist() the same DataFrame after every transformation & action?

For example:

```
var df: DataFrame = spark.read.format(...)
df.persist.count  // Cache #1

df = df.map(...)  // the 1st transformation
val tmp1 = df.filter(...).count()
df.persist.count  // Cache #2: Is this necessary? Is Cache #2 is the same obj as Cache #1 in memory? 

df = df.map(...)  // the 2nd transformation
val tmp2 = df.filter(...).count()
df.persist.count  // Cache #3: Is this necessary? Is Cache #3 is the same obj as Cache #2 in memory?
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You should not persist the dataframe after every transformation. Incase, if you are doing narrow transformation you should not do that definitely.

You should persist the dataframe only if you are doing some complex transformations and recomputing the dataframe by doing those transformation is expensive. In case of complex transformation also you should only persist if you are using that dataframe and calling multiple actions on the child dataframe that you are creating from the dataframe that you are caching or persisting.

Persist() is a transformation and it gets called on the first action you perform on the dataframe that you have cached. persist is an expensive operation as it stores that data in memory on the executor nodes so that it does not have to compute the complex transformations and can read directly the computed cached dataframe and proceed with the remaining transformation.

Also you are using a mutable variable `var` as per your question instead you should use `val` which is immutable.

Comment: Okay I'll use persisting only when there're complex transformations and need to calling multiple actions... Thank you for your advice! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can `persist` a `DataFrame` that often if you want, but it's almost certainly not necessary to do so that often.  Spark's model is to recompute if necessary, and `persist` reduces how far back it has to recompute, so it's a good idea to `persist` after particularly expensive operations.  `persist` however is not particularly cheap, especially if persisting more durably, and you pay that cost every time (while the cost of recomputing is only paid some of the time).

So the advice I've seen and concur with is to figure out the most expensive few operations and only `persist` after those.

Comment: "persist is not particularly cheap", what you say makes sense. I'll do persist only after the most expensive transformations. Thank you so much for your answer!